# Does the confirmation bias really exist?

Tags: paradox, cognitive-bias

The confirmation bias is said to be the tendency to exclude information that contradicts our belief.

But does this bias really exist ?

What if the researcher who discovered this bias only gathered facts that prove the bias and excluded facts that show that people are not subject to this tendency ?

Would it be proof that indeed the confirmation bias exists because the researcher was victim of it (even though no other proof existed)? Or do we have some kind of paradox.

Comment: Please move this question to a group on psychology. It is not a question of philosophy.

Comment: https://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2444#comic

Comment: @DavidGudeman I've seen lot of similar questions here, why would this one be a matter of psychology ?

Comment: Almost no questions ever get removed from this site because no one bothers to vote to close them, but that doesn't mean that they are appropriate for the site. Confirmation bias is a study of psychology, not epistemology. It is about how people actually reason, not about what constitutes proper reasoning.

Comment: @DavidGudeman The question of whether a phenomenon in psychology exists is a matter for the philosophy of psychology, and rightly so. Any question of existence is ontological and therefore philosophical. You have to dig deeper than 'is it a psychological question' because intersectionality allows yes to both 'is it psychology' and 'is it philosophy'.

Comment: @WaterBearer, did you seriously just call me a Nazi because I want to have a site for philosophy questions and not all of the garbage that is found everywhere else in the internet?

Comment: @DavidGudeman potentially yes. I believe that only answers can be garbage, not questions.

Comment: @WaterBearer, Comparing enforcing the rules of an internet forum to murdering millions of people is an outrage.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I'm sure you're broken up inside. But despite the fact that you've chosen to fend off a low hanging ad hominem and not address valid concerns about a very shallow reading of metaphysics is telling.

Comment: @JD, the fact that you are going through all of my comments on this forum and making snotty replies to them is telling.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Ah, [whataboutism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whataboutism). You are in the right place, to be sure! You keep at it, champ. I look forward to learning from you. :D

Answer (score 1):

Whether humans in general are affected by this is a question for psychology, not philosophy.

Studies about the confirmation bias which are themselves affected by it would be ironical, but do not pose any philosophical issue or paradox.

If humans in general were unable to study the bias because the bias **unavoidably** made **every** such study invalid, that could be more paradoxical, but there is no reason to believe that the bias cannot be avoided.

If it were, actually all scientific studies and all human reasoning would be invalid, and then asking questions in philosophy would also be pointless.

Comment: What I wanted to point out is not just that this bias can affect its own study, but that it prevents any serious conclusion. It's like a poorly calibrated screen/printer, it could be true white color but who knows ! I think that actually a great number of reasoning and science is invalid. It seems to work until we find the exception to the rule we made up ourself. Did you know that knowing a bias doesn't prevent you from it ? it's called the GI Joe bias.